# Different input format for an object in C++

Tags: c++, istream

I have recently learned how to use `cin` with objects of a class.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& aliasCin, RationalNumber& r) {
    double temp;
    aliasCin >> temp;
    r = RationalNumber(temp);

    return aliasCin;
}
```

This is my class RationalNumber, As you can see that I am taking in a double and passing it to my non-default constructor. I know how this works but ...

My question is, I also want another style to input my Rational Number such that it is in `a/b` format.
Where `a` and `b` are numerator and denominator of the Rational number. After I have found them I can

```
RationalNumber::RationalNumber (const int& a, const int& b){
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
    standardize(); // Changes the values of the object to standard form
    reduce(); // Changes the Rational Number to irreducible fraction
    count++;
}
```

First I thought of having a string as the input, finding the index of `/` in the string and then finding `a` and `b`, but I think there should be an easy way than this. Or is this the only option that I have?

Comment: You may reference the [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex ) APIS, or just it std::comprex to replace your class, especially in production code.

Comment: Tip: Use [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) and avoid the `this->` cruft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can read multiple values by chaining `cin >> a >> b >> c`.

I'm not sure how to handle the slash, this seems ok:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
        int a;
        char separator;
        int b;

        cout << "Enter a fraction (e.g. 3/4): ";
        cin >> a >> separator >> b;
        cout << endl;
        if(separator=='/'){
                //do whatever
                cout << "Beep boop... " << a << "/" << b << "=" << (float)a/b << endl;
        }
        else{
                cout << "wrong separator: " << separator << " a=" << a << ", b=" << b << endl;
        }
}
```

Sample output:

```
~$ g++ test.cpp && ./a.exe
Enter a fraction (e.g. 3/4): 3 / 4

Beep boop... 3/4=0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to simplify.

You may take a string as an argument of constructor. Let constructor to parse that string.

```
RationalNumber::RationalNumber (const std::string& s){
    // parsing stuff
}
```

It's possible but not a good solution. Because you need to let constructor to take care of parsing which should not be the responsibilty of `RationalNumber` .

Eg: In the future, will `RationalNumber` allows `r = RationalNumber("1+2/3*4-5")`?

It'stoo complicate for an simple data structure.

Let's ramp it up. What if there is another `ComplexNumber` class and it takes expression argument? Then there are two separate but similar snippet of code in two different places which leads to (plausible) hard to maintain code.

Leave expression parser does parsing job.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, but I have a question. What would the function definition look like if I wanted to `cin >> r`, such that if I enter `-2.4` or `-12/5` it should make the same object, as -2.4 and -12/5 are equal.

Comment: @blackmamba You need a c++ mathematical expression parser. There are many libraries out there. (Eg: on github). I don't have experience about this and SO doesn't accept question for recommending libraries nowadays.